# Which method is more efficient when it comes to fetching data from database?

Tags: mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to fetch user data from MySQL database and output it in a HTML table.

I found a jQuery plugin that automatically sorts tables and allows users to sort, limit and add paging to data: [jQuery dataTables Plugin](https://datatables.net/)

But I will have to output all of my users data at once.

So my question is, should I output all data at once and use dataTables to allow users to sort the data however they want?

Or should I use AJAX and output, say for example, 20 users and fetch the next 20 rows from database using AJAX when user tries to go to the next page? Keep in mind, I will need to send AJAX call everytime the user wants to sort (order) the data as well.

My main goal is to optimize database and reduce pressure on it.

Comment: In general: Paging is only necessary when there is a lot of result data. For a few hundred rows, it's usually much simpler to do the sorting and paging client side unless you have very restricted bandwidth. Also: When you have a lot of data and the user will typically only view the first few pages, fetching the full dataset is also pointless.

Comment: I have a rule of thumb, if I see less than 1000 rows, I get it all at once. More than that, I start paging to the server.  In my application I actually  have thousands of rows but I didn't not want to go to the server every time they click a page so I used an edited form of the pipeline code that you can find on the datatables site

Comment: here is the pipeline link https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your dataset size.

See [Data - Processing modes](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Processing-modes) for more details.

> As a rule of thumb, if you are working with less than 10,000 rows use client-side processing, for greater than 100,000 rows use server-side processing. In-between is a grey area where you will need to make a decision based upon the nature of your app and the data you wish to display!